# How to get data from angular service to controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have response from server in success , How can i send that to controller i tried then method but its throwing error then is nto defined, How can i achieve this task ?

service.js

```
angular.module('App').service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        console.log('service called', fd);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(resp){
        console.log('success',resp);
        return resp;
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);
```

controller.js

```
  $scope.uploadFile = function(){
                var file = $scope.myFile;
                // console.log('file is ');
                // console.dir(file);
                // console.log(file);
                var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
                fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl).then(function(resp){console.log(resp);
};
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using the `.success` (which is deprecated anyway) in the service, and just return the promise itself.

```
angular.module('App')

.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        // ... other code ...
        // return the $http promise itself here
        return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
    }
}])
```

Then in your controller (the .catch is optional, but good to use if your $promise errors out).

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(){
    // ... other code ...
    var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";

    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl)
        .then(function(response) { console.log(response) })
        .catch(function(error) { console.log(error) });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the Promise, only then you will be able to use `then` in the controller.

```
angular.module('App').service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
 this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    console.log('service called', fd);
    return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
 }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this.

```
angular.module('App').service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
  this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    console.log('service called', fd);
    return $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    });
  }
}

$scope.uploadFile = function() {
  var file = $scope.myFile;
  // console.log('file is ');
  // console.dir(file);
  // console.log(file);
  var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
  fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl)
    .then(function(resp) {
    console.log('Your response here', resp);
  });
};
```